# Transform JSON element to SQL Table Format

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

This question is in relation to my previous problem which was solved.
[Link to Previous Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69688530/sql-server-parse-json-string-to-a-sql-table-format/69688565#69688598)

Now I need to access columns and values of the Tag "GetCustomReportResult" and transform into a SQL Table format.

The JSON String is actually stored in a column in a SQL Table as seen below and I am trying to transform the elements in the tag "GetCustomReportResult" in a table format with columns and values for each of the "ApplicationID":
[image]

Here is what I was trying to access the columns and values within the Tag "GetCustomReportResult":

```
SELECT 
y.cijreport,
y.ApplicationId,
JSON_VALUE(x.value, '$.CIP') as CIP,
JSON_VALUE(x.value, '$.CIQ') as CIQ
--other fields
FROM table as y
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (cijreport) as x
where cijreport is not null
```

I now get this error when I execute:

> Msg 13609, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'o' is found at position 0.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] which should include at least one of the JSON rows *as text* not pictures. Please also show your full SQL query, and your expected results, again *as text*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are missing the JSON path `'$.data.response'`.

Next, you can't use `JSON_VALUE` on a whole object, it's only good for scalar values. You can either use `JSON_QUERY`:

```sql
SELECT 
  y.cijreport,
  y.ApplicationId,
  JSON_QUERY(x.value, '$.CIP') as CIP,
  JSON_QUERY(x.value, '$.CIQ') as CIQ, x.VALUE
--other fields
FROM YourTable as y
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (cijreport, '$.data.response') as x;
```

Or you can specify property names in `OPENJSON`

```sql
SELECT 
  y.cijreport,
  y.ApplicationId,
  x.CIP,
  x.CIQ
--other fields
FROM YourTable as y
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (cijreport, '$.data.response')
  WITH (
    CIP nvarchar(max) AS JSON,
    CIQ nvarchar(max) AS JSON
  ) AS x;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ecc14eb8818dd38e3b26b78981dff022)

Note that the `where cijreport is not null` filter is not necessary, because `CROSS APPLY OPENJSON` will return 0 rows in such a case, and `CROSS APPLY` acts like an inner join.